# Passing custom data with map pin segue

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2

I've been having trouble figuring out how to pass a custom variable in a map pin to another view controller in Swift. I know that passing the                 coordinates, title, and subtitle are available when you addAnnotation. I would like to try and pass a custom variable but hidden. Is there such a thing? Below I am getting the users location, mapping it, dropping a pin of a couple locations nearby with annotations which goes to another view controller and passes just the title and subtitle. Any insight is greatly appreciated.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

var mappedCity = String()
var mappedState = String()

var manager = CLLocationManager()
var annotation:MKAnnotation!
var error:NSError!
var pointAnnotation:MKPointAnnotation!
var pinAnnotationView:MKPinAnnotationView!
var selectedAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation!

private var mapChangedFromUserInteraction = false

@IBOutlet var mapView: MKMapView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.mapView.delegate = self
    self.navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar
    self.definesPresentationContext = true


    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled(){
        manager.delegate = self
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()

   }       

}


func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    let userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0]
    let latitude = userLocation.coordinate.latitude
    let longitude = userLocation.coordinate.longitude

    let latDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.05
    let lonDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.05
    let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latDelta, lonDelta)
    let location:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
    let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span)

    self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true

    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(userLocation) { (placemarks, error) in

        if (error != nil){

            print(error)

        }else {

            if let p = placemarks?[0]{

                let locality = p.locality ?? ""
                let administrativeArea = p.administrativeArea ?? ""


                self.mappedCity = String(locality)
                self.mappedState = String(administrativeArea)

                self.parseJSON("\(locality)", state: "\(administrativeArea)")
            }

        }



    }
 self.manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}


func parseJSON(city: String, state: String){
    let passedCity = city
    let passedState = state
    let escapedCity = passedCity.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())!
    let escapedState = passedState.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())!

    let url = NSURL(string:"http://www.API.com/api.php?city=\(escapedCity)&stateAbv=\(escapedState)")!

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url) { (items, response, error) -> Void in

        if error != nil {

            print(error)


        }else {


            if let items = items {


                do {
                    let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(items, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary

                    if jsonResult.count > 0 {

                        if let datas = jsonResult["data"] as? NSArray{

                            for data in datas{

                                if let title = data["title"] as? String {

                                    if let street = data["street"] as? String {

                                        if let city =  data["city"] as? String {

                                            if let stateAbv =  data["stateAbv"] as? String {

                                                if let zip =  data["zip"] as? String {

                                                    self.geoAddress("\(title)", street: "\(street)", city: "\(city)", state: "\(stateAbv)", zip: "\(zip)")


                                                }
                                            }
                                        }

                                    }

                                }

                            }
                        }

                    }
                } catch{}


            }


        }

    }

    task.resume()

}


func geoAddress(title: String, street: String, city: String, state: String, zip: String){
    let storeName = "\(title)"
    let location = "\(street) \(city) \(state) \(zip)"
    let geocoder = CLGeocoder();
    geocoder.geocodeAddressString(location, completionHandler: {(placemarks: [CLPlacemark]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            print("Error \(error!)")
        } else if let placemark = placemarks?[0] {

            let coordinates:CLLocationCoordinate2D = placemark.location!.coordinate

            let pointAnnotation:MKPointAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            pointAnnotation.coordinate = coordinates
            pointAnnotation.title = storeName
            pointAnnotation.subtitle = location

            self.mapView.addAnnotation(pointAnnotation)

        }
    })
}


private func mapViewRegionDidChangeFromUserInteraction() -> Bool {
    let view: UIView = self.mapView.subviews[0] as UIView
    //  Look through gesture recognizers to determine whether this region change is from user interaction
    if let gestureRecognizers = view.gestureRecognizers {
        for recognizer in gestureRecognizers {
            if( recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began || recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended ) {
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, regionWillChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
    mapChangedFromUserInteraction = mapViewRegionDidChangeFromUserInteraction()
    if (mapChangedFromUserInteraction) {
        // user changed map region

    }
}

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
    if (mapChangedFromUserInteraction) {
        // user changed map region
        let center = mapView.centerCoordinate

        let mapLatitude = center.latitude
        let mapLongitude = center.longitude


        let locationmove = CLLocation(latitude: mapLatitude, longitude: mapLongitude)
        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(locationmove) { (placemarks, error) in

            if (error != nil){

                print(error)

            }else {

                if let p = placemarks?[0]{

                    let locality = p.locality ?? ""
                    let administrativeArea = p.administrativeArea ?? ""


                     self.mappedCity = String(locality)
                     self.mappedState = String(administrativeArea)
                     self.parseJSON("\(locality)", state: "\(administrativeArea)")
                }

            } 

        }
    }
}



func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        return nil
    }

    let reuseId = "pin"
    var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId) as? MKPinAnnotationView
    if pinView == nil {
        pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
        pinView?.animatesDrop = false
        pinView?.canShowCallout = true
        pinView?.draggable = true
        pinView?.pinTintColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        let rightButton: AnyObject! = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure)
        pinView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton as? UIView
    }
    else {
        pinView?.annotation = annotation
    }

    return pinView
}

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
    if control == view.rightCalloutAccessoryView {
        selectedAnnotation = view.annotation as? MKPointAnnotation
        performSegueWithIdentifier("Details", sender: self)
    }
}

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, didChangeDragState newState: MKAnnotationViewDragState, fromOldState oldState: MKAnnotationViewDragState) {
    if newState == MKAnnotationViewDragState.Ending {
        let droppedAt = view.annotation?.coordinate
        print(droppedAt)
    }
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

   if (segue.identifier == "Details"){
   let myDetails = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController
     myDetails.mytitle = selectedAnnotation.title
     myDetails.mysubtitle = selectedAnnotation.subtitle

    }

}


func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {


}


}
```

Comment: You should reduce the code posted here and only show what you believe is relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Subclass` the "MKPointAnnotation" class and add your `custom property` in it.

```
class MyAnnotation : MKPointAnnotation {
    var customProperty : String?
}
```

And you can use `MyAnnotation` instead of `MKPointAnnotation`. Like following

```
 let pointAnnotation:MyAnnotation = MyAnnotation()
 pointAnnotation.coordinate = coordinates
 pointAnnotation.title = storeName
 pointAnnotation.subtitle = location
 pointAnnotation.customProperty = "your value"
 self.mapView.addAnnotation(pointAnnotation)
```

Comment: Awesome! This worked out great. Thank you very much!